# Raspberry Pi Bottle webserver, change webpage when button is pressed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bottle

I have a Raspberry Pi with a bottle webserver running. I've connected several reed switches to the Pi. The idea is when a switch is activated, the server will automatic "push" a webpage to the clients. Now, when I activate a switch. I first have to refresh the page before I'm redirected. I've only written a script for one switch so far. See below for my script:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, error
from bottle import redirect, request, response

switch1 = 38
led1 = 40

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(switch1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(led1, GPIO.OUT)

@route("/")
def hello():
    if not GPIO.input(switch1):
        GPIO.output(led1, True)
        return template("video1.html")
    else:
        GPIO.output(led1, False)
        return template("index.html")

@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return("Nothing here, keep searching!")

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: What's in your page before refreshing it? I think you could add some JS triggered by a signal from the server, (sent when the switch is activated) perhaps something like a websocket to automatically refresh the page. If you just send some HTML without JS, your client won't "know" that you activated a switch. And that's the client who send the request, not the server who "push" and force some page change.

Comment: Yeah, ship your pages with javascript that polls in a loop (or uses [long polling](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/http-long-polling/)) to detect when one of your switches has been depressed.

Comment: The page before refreshing is video1.html or index.html, depends if I've pressed the button or not. Could you please give an example on how to use JS in this case? I've practically no experience with Javascript.